# Stage for Hud not visible

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a GameScreen with a SpriteBatch to draw all my textures on, but I want to add a pause button on the screen now. I've tried to use a stage on top of my SpriteBatch, but for some reason it won't show up.

Here's some of the code:

The constructor:

```
public GameScreen(MyGame game) {

    stage = new Stage();
    table = new Table();

    pause_texture = new Texture("path_to_texture.png");
    pause_image = new Image(pause_texture);
    pause_image.setPosition(1920 - pause_image.getWidth() - 20, 20);

    table.add(pause_image);
    stage.addActor(table);
}
```

The render method:

```
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();

    game.camera.update();

    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(game.camera.combined);

    game.batch.begin();
    //rendering stuff here
    game.batch.end();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: on your setPosition what are the value of pause_button.getWidth()? shouldn't it be pause_image.getWidth()?

Comment: oh, yeah, it should be pause_image.getWidth(), I have that in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use absolute positions on a Table, just do something like this:

```
public GameScreen(MyGame game){

    stage = new Stage();
    table = new Table();

    pause_texture = new Texture("path_to_texture.png");
    pause_image = new Image(pause_texture);

    table.add(pause_image);
    table.bottom().right();
    stage.addActor(table);

}
```

For further reference look at [Table](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table) on the Libgdx Wiki

Don't forget to move stage.act(delta); and stage.draw(); to after batch.end(), the GUI is the last thing that should be rendered so it can be in the front of everything.

Comment: Hmm, yea I tried that now, and the stage still wouldn't show up

Comment: @Anton call table.setFillParent(true); after creating the table, and stage.setDebugAll(true);

Comment: move stage.act(delta); stage.draw(); to after game.batch.end(), the stage should be the last thing you should draw so it will be on front of the screen..